# Reproducing git branching model with help of mercurial bookmarks

Tags: git, mercurial, git-branch

I am trying to use Mercurial and I want to reproduce git branching model with help of Bookmark extension. Here is the problem with that.

Imagine I have a repostory. I've added 2 bookmarks

```
user@host:/tmp/hgtest$ hg bookmark main
user@host:/tmp/hgtest$ hg bookmark feature
user@host:/tmp/hgtest$ hg bookmarks 
 * feature                   0:76c6736b4548
   main                      0:76c6736b4548
```

After that i've commited some code and decided that feature is ready (no development on this feature in near future). At this moment bookmarks point to different commits.

```
user@host:/tmp/hgtest$ hg bookmarks
 * feature                   2:9d32bb6bdbc6
   main                      0:76c6736b4548
```

Now i am switching back to the state where i've started development of my feature

```
user@host:/tmp/hgtest$ hg up main
resolving manifests
removing second.file
getting first.file
1 files updated, 0 files merged, 1 files removed, 0 files unresolved
```

I would like to issue `merge` command in order to make history graph looking like this

```
user@host:/tmp/test-git$ git log --graph
*   commit d8a957350fc8fbaf542e20aac0d4c95477cc2d3c
|\  Merge: 20493a7 7b59a16
| | Author: Author
| | Date:   Mon Jul 11 18:35:09 2011 +1100
| | 
| |     Merge branch 'testfeature'
| |   
| * commit 7b59a16d0b01d9bcc22f21a3c68f63acf60f37da
| | Author: Author
| | Date:   Mon Jul 11 18:34:34 2011 +1100
| | 
| |     Added line to test.file
| |   
| * commit 20ea105cf300f7f3e952ac7eddffd2aee6811f7c
|/  Author: Author
|   Date:   Mon Jul 11 18:32:27 2011 +1100
|   
|       Added code for testfeature
|  
* commit 20493a7a61705967b092780cae9fadd76ec49019
  Author: Author
  Date:   Mon Jul 11 18:25:17 2011 +1100
```

but Mercurial doesn't allow this

```
user@host:/tmp/hgtest$ hg merge feature
abort: nothing to merge (use 'hg update' or check 'hg heads')
user@host:/tmp/hgtest$
```

I want to reproduce git approach since it allows to break giant line of development commits into bunches of feature related commits, make it easier to understand history.

If I can achieve such behaviour using another technique please feel free to share it with me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you might be on to something.

Mercurial doesn't have "fast-forward" merges, in git terms. This is what it's telling you: there's nothing to merge, you should `hg update feature` instead. But that won't move your `main` bookmark to where you want it to be (and it will also change your current bookmark).

That basically forces you to `hg bookmark -f main` right after updating, which doesn't seem right.

I'll take this up to mercurial-devel mailing list to see what the rest think and update this answer once I have some news.

Comment: Are there any news from dev list?

Comment: @Konstantin: there's this issue I opened on the bts: http://mercurial.selenic.com/bts/issue2894 for now it looks like it doesn't scratch anyones itch...

Comment: Thank you. I will keep an eye on this issue. I am closing the question right now.